# No locate.db even after running updatedb

Tags: gentoo, locate

Any clue what's up with this?

```
djc@miles rebar $ sudo updatedb
djc@miles rebar $ locate .dialyzer_plt
locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory
djc@miles rebar $ sudo su -l
miles ~ # cd /var/lib/mlocate/
miles mlocate # ls -l
total 51576
-rw------- 1 root root  6553600 Oct  1 03:13 mlocate.db.AkeorG
-rw------- 1 root root  6635520 Oct  3 03:14 mlocate.db.EY0KT9
-rw------- 1 root root  6639616 Oct  4 10:34 mlocate.db.EiWVGW
-rw------- 1 root root  6230016 Sep 30 03:14 mlocate.db.Shbi49
-rw------- 1 root root 13447168 Sep 29 14:40 mlocate.db.VAo6El
-rw------- 1 root root  6668288 Oct  4 03:12 mlocate.db.gTyzDl
-rw------- 1 root root  6635520 Oct  2 03:12 mlocate.db.o0nXlW
```

Comment: You could try running `updatedb -v` for some more verbose output.

Comment: `s/sudo su -l/sudo -i/g`

Comment: a dirty fix is do a `mv` manually

Answer (score 1):

When mlocate finish the updatedb, write the final file with the user root and other group. Verify the permissions in the directory "mlocate":

```
drwxr-x--- 2 root slocate 4096 Oct 25 18:02 mlocate
```

Comment: If he don't have the permission to write files here..how could these temp files occur?

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling the mlocate package. It looks like you might have some corruption